# How to add list of parameters from JSON to HashMap?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

Kindly, I've searched all the way around and tried to implement it in different ways. But I need some advice.

I have following Map in my Java class (with static items commented out)

```
    /**
 * An array of YouTube videos
 */


public static List<YouTubeVideo> ITEMS = new ArrayList<>();

/**
 * A map of YouTube videos, by ID.
 */


public static Map<String, YouTubeVideo> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<>();



/*
static {

    addItem(new YouTubeVideo("x-hH_Txxzls", "Titlee 2"));
    addItem(new YouTubeVideo("TTh_qYMzSZk", "Title 3"));
    addItem(new YouTubeVideo("tttG6SdnCd4", "Some Title"));
    addItem(new YouTubeVideo("x-hH_Txxzls", "This post title"));
    addItem(new YouTubeVideo("TTh_qYMzSZk", "Post title"));
    addItem(new YouTubeVideo("tttG6SdnCd4", "Titles"));
    addItem(new YouTubeVideo("x-hH_Txxzls", "again titles"));

}*/


private void addItem(final YouTubeVideo item) {
    ITEMS.add(item);
    ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
}

/**
 * A POJO representing a YouTube video
 */
public static class YouTubeVideo {
    public String id;
    public String title;

    public YouTubeVideo(String id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = content;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

And this my parser (right now it sends data to another list and its woking well)

```
private void getData(){
    //Showing a progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"Loading Data", "Please wait...",false,false);

    //Creating a json array request
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Dismissing progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //calling method to parse json array
                    parseData(response);

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

}

private void parseData(JSONArray array){
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        IndividualPosts IndividualPost = new IndividualPosts();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            IndividualPost.setTitleIn(json.getString(Config.TAG_TITLE));
            IndividualPost.setLink(json.getString(Config.TAG_VIDEO_ID));


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listIndividualPosts.add(IndividualPost);
    }

    //Finally initializing our adapter
    adapter = new CardAdapter(listIndividualPosts, getActivity());

    //Adding adapter to recyclerview
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

But I can't get on how to send data to this hashMap, in the same way as I have static items :(

The main concern is that HashMap should have a list of items as it can be updated. 
Basically, it creates a list of posts with title and videoThumbnail.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like this

```
public static void addItem(YouTubeVideo item) {
    ITEMS.add(item);
    ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
}
```

Then add these inside try block

```
YouTubeVideo youtubeVideo = new YouTubeVideo(
      json.getString(Config.TAG_VIDEO_ID), json.getString(Config.TAG_TITLE));

Config.addItem(youtubeVideo); // assuming addItem in class Config
```

Also make `YouTubeVideo` as non-static like or better create this class in independent Java file

```
public class YouTubeVideo {
```

Comment: hm, what do you mean by "after: listIndividualPosts.add(IndividualPost);
" ?
note: my code samples - are 2 different files.

Comment: Yes I understand. First update your method in first java class, then add those two lines in other java class.

Comment: this way it throws unhandled exception org.json.jsonexception as its not handled (if I add this code right after          

   listIndividualPosts.add(IndividualPost);

P.S. addItem locates in the same file as Map, so I changed Config to required java class. thx

Comment: @OliverWhite: Oh I am sorry put those two lines inside `try` block.

Comment: I'm trying it with                         json.getString(Config.TAG_VIDEO_ID).substring(13, json.getString(Config.TAG_VIDEO_ID).length() - 2), json.getString(Config.TAG_TITLE).substring(118, json.getString(Config.TAG_VIDEO_ID).length() - 73));
 
because my strings contains html tags and another crap, right now app is crashing :(

Comment: also, if I place something like
addItem(new YouTubeVideo("x-hH_Txxzls", "Titlee 2"));
outside of the static it throws errors

Comment: System.out.println(youtubeVideo);
without substring produces: content